# Is it possible to use asp.net httprequests to send data to PHPmyadmin?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin

I developed a website over php that sends and retrieve data from phpmyadmin. Through this way, I want to be able to send data from my smart phone (android) to phpmyadmin and I was told that this can be done through HTTPrequests; however, I was also told that it is possible on asp.net only.

My application (as a test) is built to just register a user and let him/her get logged in. I am just stuck to the point where I am not sure how to send data from the phone to phpmyadmin..

> Is it possible to just use asp.net to **retrieve** and **send** data
>   using **httprequests** and then **post** them on phpmyadmin? Or do I just redo
>   my entire website over asp.net?

I have little knowledge about asp.net, but I would just like to hear an opinion from the professionals on this website!

Comment: Ask something more concise, the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: There's no need for ASP.NET to do this, but it certainly *can*. My guess is you are misunderstanding something fundamental in the advice you were given. Or, you got advice from someone fundamentally confused.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the response. Around here, we don't have much tech savy people and it helps me think knowing someone can tell me YES ITS POSSIBLE.

Comment: In that case, let me save you some time and tell you that the answer to just about every broad "is it possible" question is "yes". You need to ask more concise questions.